# Error: Cannot find module 'polka' on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, svelte, sapper

I'm trying to deploy my sapper/svelte app to heroku but getting 'Error: Cannot find module 'polka'' this error. Interesting thing is that, it was perfectly fine and working. My package.json is correct and I am not checking my modules into git either. I tried disabling caching but it is no good. Anyone have any ideas?

```
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083385+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'polka'
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083386+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083386+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/__sapper__/build/server/server.js
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083386+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/__sapper__/build/index.js
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083387+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083392+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083392+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083393+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083393+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/__sapper__/build/server/server.js:4:13)
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083394+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083394+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083394+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083395+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083395+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19) {
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083396+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083396+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083397+00:00 app[web.1]:     '/app/__sapper__/build/server/server.js',
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083397+00:00 app[web.1]:     '/app/__sapper__/build/index.js'
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083397+00:00 app[web.1]:   ]
2020-09-16T16:04:44.083398+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out polka's version on my package.json was set to 'next'. So I changed it to it latest stable version and deleted package.lock.json file and ran 'npm install' to create a new lock file and then pushed it to heroku. Works perfectly fine.